# python bot telegram and twitter

Tags: python, twitter, telegram

[hello I want to create a bot to share telegram messages on twitter, but I am getting the error of ( messages = bot.get_chat(chat_id=channel_id).get_last_message(count=10)
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get_last_message')

follow the code. can anybody help me ?

```
import telegram
import tweepy

# Twitter API keys
consumer_key = "x"
consumer_secret = "x"
access_token = "x"
access_token_secret = "x"

# Telegram Bot API token
telegram_token = "x"

# Telegram chat ID to get messages from
channel_id = -1001679200115

# Authenticate with Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Connect to Telegram Bot API
bot = telegram.Bot(token=telegram_token)

# Get the last 10 messages from the chat
messages = bot.get_chat(chat_id=channel_id).get_last_message(count=10)

# Share each message on Twitter
for message in messages:
    tweet = f"{message.text}\n\n{message.link}"
    api.update_status(tweet)
    print(f"Tweet sent: {tweet}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, you should change  `messages = bot.get_chat(chat_id=channel_id).get_last_message(count=10)` line to this:

```
chat = await bot.get_chat(chat_id=channel_id)
messages = await chat.get_last_message(count=10)
```

Await refers to the “await” expression used with coroutines. You can learn more about Python asynchronous programming [here](https://superfastpython.com/async-await-python/).